# $y=\frac{\log \left(3x^2\right)}{\log \left(\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)^{12^x}\right)}$ Why is one of the roots $\pi$?

Tags: functions

I was graphing random functions and came across this one

$$y=\frac{\log \left(3x^2\right)}{\log \left(\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)^{12^x}\right)}$$

When graphing it:[image]

I found that a root is $\pi$ however when plugging this into our function the demoninator becomes $\log(0)$ which is undefined. How can the root be $\pi$?

Comment: Just as you say: the function is not defined at $\pi$, so $\pi$ is not a root.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Uhhh I thought a root is something which makes a function = zero?

Comment: The function is not equal to zero when $x=\pi$ because the function is undefined at $x=\pi$.  We conclude from this that $\pi$ is not a root.

Comment: If you don't mind, I shall reuse this function which is quite interesting. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Haha sure , just wondering why would you reuse it? What's so interesting about it?

Comment: The variations are so slow close to $\pi$ ! The asymptotics is quite nice. As you see, we can deduce everything from the last edit of my answer basically with no computation..

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici To think I found this function by plugging random functions everywhere! :-)

Comment: If you generate other functions of this kind, please let me know.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I just go on https://www.desmos.com/calculator and start writing random functions , usually change around the denominator since thats when the function starts getting interesting due to the asymptotes and such. I'm just a highschool student so I'm not really sure what I am doing but I find it cool how such functions can have breaks randomly and start back up again.

Comment: What you do reveals a lot of good things about you ! Jus go on and try to understand how behave you random functions. This is very good self-teaching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=\pi$, $\sin(\pi)=0$, so $\sin^{-1}\left(\sin(\pi)\right)=0$.

And then $\left(\sin^{-1}\left(\sin(\pi)\right)\right)^{12^\pi}=0$

And then if you try taking $\log$ of this, you can't. But if $x$ had been just shy of $\pi$, then you'd be taking $\log$ of a number barely larger than $0$. So the $\log$ would be a huge negative number.

Then $\frac{\log(3x^2)}{\log(\cdots)}$ is like $\frac{c}{-\infty}$. (This is very informal.)

Answer (score 2):

When $x$ is near $\pi$, the numerator is approximately $\ln 3\pi^2\approx 3.388$. Suppose that $x=\pi-\epsilon$, where $\epsilon$ is a small positive number. Then $\sin^{-1}\sin x=\sin\epsilon\approx\epsilon$, and $\epsilon^{12^x}$ is a very small positive number. Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^-}\ln\left(\left(\sin^{-1}\sin x\right)^{12^x}\right)=-\infty\;,$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to\pi^-}\frac{\ln\left(3x^2\right)}{\ln\left(\left(\sin^{-1}\sin x\right)^{12^x}\right)}=0\;,$$

approached from below, just as the graph indicates. The function is undefined for $x\ge\pi$, however.

Answer (score 1):

As said in answers, let $$x=\pi-10^{-k}$$ and let us compute the value of the function $y$ for different values of $k$. We should get 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & y \\
 5 & -0.0001197920 \\
 10 & -0.0000598948 \\
 15 & -0.0000399299 \\
 20 & -0.0000299474 \\
 25 & -0.0000239579 \\
 30 & -0.0000199649 \\
 35 & -0.0000171128 \\
 40 & -0.0000149737 \\
 45 & -0.0000133100 \\
 50 & -0.0000119790
\end{array}
\right)$$ which goes very, very slowly to $0$ but will never reach it since $y$ is not defined for $x=\pi$. For $k=1000$, we should get something like $y\approx -5.99\times 10^{-7}$.

Going deeper and setting $k=10^n$, it seems that the value of $y$ is given by $$y\approx -5.99\times 10^{-(n+4)}$$

**Edit**

Making things more formal, let us consider

$$y=\frac{\log \left(3x^2\right)}{\log \left(\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)^{12^x}\right)}=\frac{\log \left(3x^2\right)}{{12^x}\log \left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)}$$ and use Taylor series (an compositions of them) around $\epsilon=0$ with $x=\pi-\epsilon$ $$\sin(x)=\sin(\pi-\epsilon)=\sin(\epsilon)=\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$ $$\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=\epsilon +O\left(\epsilon ^3\right)$$
$$\log \left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)=\log (\epsilon )+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ $$12^x=12^\pi\times 12^{-\epsilon}=12^\pi\left(1-\epsilon  \log (12)+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)\right)$$ All of the above makes the denominnator to be $$\log \left(\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\sin \left(x\right)\right)\right)^{12^x}\right)=12^\pi\left(\log (\epsilon )-\epsilon  \log (12) \log (\epsilon )+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)\right)$$ For the numerator $$\log(3x^2)=\log \left(3 \pi ^2\right)-\frac{2 \epsilon }{\pi }+O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$$ All of that finally makes $$y=\frac{12^{-\pi } \log \left(3 \pi ^2\right)}{\log (\epsilon )}+O\left(\epsilon
   \right)$$ Setting $\epsilon=10^{-k}$ then leads to $$y\approx -\frac{12^{-\pi } \log \left(3 \pi ^2\right)}{\log (10 )}\times \frac 1 k\approx -\frac {5.98948 \times 10^{-4}} k$$ from which all above results.